# How to obtain html object using jQuery's $.get()

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to assign a variable that is the object of a HTML element using the get() method with an index as defined in the docs(1).

For example I have an container div that has child divs with a class child-div.

```
<div>
    <div class="child-div"></div>
    <div class="child-div"></div>
    <div class="child-div"></div>
</div>
```

If I want to retrieve the second div I can use: `myDiv = $('.child-div').get(1);`

However this returns a string of the contents of the div but I want to add styles and treat it as a normal object. How do I assign myDiv as an object?

(1) http://api.jquery.com/get/

Comment: `typeof myDiv` returns object.

Comment: `$('.child-div').get(1)` returns a DOM object not a string.  The premise of your question is just wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get` doesn't actually return a string, it returns a DOM object. However, when you print it out into the console it does kind of look like it's just a string. To edit its the css you can just do something like `myDiv.style.fontSize = "50px";`

However, since you're already using jQuery, you could also do something like this, `myDiv = $('.child-div:eq(1)');`. Here `eq(1)` selects the second div like `.get(1)` does.

Then you could use jQuery's `.css()` method to change the CSS

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/lw7360/3L2Xq/) a JSFiddle that shows both ways.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You're right, it is actually an object despite looking like a string. What I'm ultimately trying to do is find a child element (nested 6 or so layers deep) that I want to target and ultimately set as the focus.

Can you please check the my JSFiddle example of what I'm trying to do. Why can't I use the find() method on the object?

http://jsfiddle.net/xW95A/

Comment: So, `get` returns a JavaScript reference to the element, not a jQuery one. Thus, you can't use the jQuery method `find` on what `get` returns. You should use the `.eq()` method instead of `.get()`, and then you can call use `find()` on the object returned from `.eq()`. [jsfiddle.net/lw7360/qJxJ4/](http://jsfiddle.net/lw7360/qJxJ4/)